# Unset variables and methods

Tags: java

I have an abstract class that is extended to provide standard methods and variables that I need.
This time, however, I have to extend the same class but some variables and some methods do not serve me. So I was wondering if it was possible to turn off these variables / methods useless. I specify that I'm forced to extend this class, I can not create another.
For example, i have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class A {
    protected int a, b, c;

    public abstract void A();
    public abstract void B();
    public abstract void C();
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        a = 5;
        b = 7;

        A();
        B();
    }

    public void A() {
        System.out.println("A: " + a);
    }

    public void B() {
        System.out.println("B: " + b);
    }

    //Unset the variable 'c' and the method 'C()' because they are useless
}
```

Actually I do not know if it's worth it to do it, I rely on your knowledge.

Comment: You can declare, `class B` as abstract.

Comment: Are you able to change class A?

Comment: @PrerakSola If I declare B as abstract, I can redefine the variables and methods?

Comment: @Simon Yes, I can change the class A.

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the non required variables/class in `class B`, if you make it abstract.

Comment: Well when you define B abstract you can't instantiate it! and doing it would be cumbersome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bad behavior and it is advised to split your class hierarchy by pulling the common members of `A` and `B` in a new abstract super class and letting the rest which is specific to the class hierarchy of `A` in `A`.

This leeds to a situation similar to

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    protected int a, b;

    public abstract void A();
    public abstract void B();
}

public abstract class A extends BaseClass {
    protected int c;

    public abstract void C();
}

public class B extends BaseClass {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in mechanism to 'unset' a variable or a method of a superclass.

The standard solution is to create two base class.

```
public abstract class A {
    protected int a, b;

    public abstract void A();
    public abstract void B();
}

public abstract class AC extends A {
    protected int c;

    public abstract void C();
}
```

A (terrible) workaround, which only works with method, could be to implement something like the below code to forbid the use of `C()`.

```
@Override
public void C() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This method is not allowed for this class");
}
```

Long story short, `javac` will accept the use `C()`, but a `RuntimeException` will be released on runtime. This exception will produce a crash if not catched, but because of the nature of `RuntimeException`, the compiler doesn't need a `try` statement...
Well, that's just an ugly piece of code =P

A cleaner workaround was proposed by Nick L. on another response, consisting to set `C()` as private.

Comment: Perhaps also describe the caveats of the workaround? (It does have its disadvantages, and we wouldn't want OP (or anybody else reading this question) to shoot themselves in the foot ...).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, this is bad design. If there are methods/fields that are not going to be needed in derived classed, then you should put them in another abstract class and derives the previous one.

As a workaround, I think you can set as private the function you want to be publicly inaccessible in `B` class if you want it not to be abstract:

```
public class B extends A {

    //c property is private.

    public B() {
        a = 5;
        b = 7;

        A();
        B();
    }

    public void A() {
        System.out.println("A: " + a);
    }

    public void B() {
        System.out.println("B: " + b);
    }

    //This is set as publicly inaccessible, although implementation is provided.
    private void C() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way you can do is make `method c` as `abstract`. So no need of implementation. if you need this in later sub classes you can use it

```
public abstract void C();
```